# How to log HTTP message body of incoming POST - Flask

Tags: python, http, flask, google-api

I'm setting up google pub/sub on a Flask server and have successfully set the endpoint to POST to `https://myapp.ngrok.io/pubsub/push/` according to [the documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/pubsub).

In my console it returns this request with a `400` error:

```
66.102.8.237 - - [24/Oct/2019:04:30:35 +0000] "POST /pubsub/push/ HTTP/1.1" 400 148 "-" "APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)"
```

I'm trying to access the message body to troubleshoot the `400` error but haven't been able to print the message body using `print(request.get_json())`.

Is there a way I can access the HTTP message body in Flask or is the above error the only information sent to my app?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP header data for the request is stored inside the `header` attribute `requests`. So for example, if you do,

```
print(request.header)
```

you'd get something like this on the console:

```
Host: localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: csrftoken=CQmXNt256FqZev0S2fRtw04ZSTlUnvYHGRbNn6NH5OVn36W7qPMZw0s9N3anGHMG
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: I've added this in my Flask views file but nothing is printed to the console apart from the single line I've posted above. I believe the 400 error has something to do with CSRF protection but I can't see the error message to confirm it.